# criar mascara customizada unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Como criar uma mascara para data na plataforma unity 3D, de forma que, quando eu for digitando, ele coloca automaticamente os caracteres "/"?

Exemplo: `00/00/0000`

Comment: unity3D, aceita Javascript?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza No unit você pode programar em Javascript ou C#

Comment: @Evandro O que você já fez do teu projeto?

Comment: De maneira geral você terá que fazer um código que verifique o texto que foi digitado e adicione as barras. Como você não deu maiores detalhes eu diria que a implementação será feita no método onGui da classe que controlará o que quer que seja que você está fazendo. Mas pode não ser nada disso... enfim

Comment: Estou usando c# posso fazer uma mistura com javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evandro não sei como você chama uma function utilizando unity3D, mas a function abaixo faz o que você precisa.

```
function mdata(v) {
  v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");

  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "$1$2");
  return v;
}
```

Comment: É nessa linha mesmo, assim que ele disser qual a implementação dele vamos saber. No momento eu chutaria que ele vai usar isso na função OnGui() em alguma classe controladora ativa.